# Как в Old или Request передать переменную в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, requests

Всем привет.

есть Request в нем массив

```
"filter" => array:6 [▼
    21 => "21"
    22 => "22"
    23 => "23"
    2 => "2"
    5 => "5"
    8 => "8"
  ]
```

мне нежно или через Request или Old вытащить значение, как я делаю но у меня не получается.

```
$v = 21;
old('filter.{$v}')
old('filter.'{{$v}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
$v = 21;
{{old('filter'.$v)}}
```

Comment: перед filter нужно поставить точку т.е old('filter.'.$v)